# How do set properties in anonymous?

Tags: c#, code-behind, anonymous-types

Hi can I generate this type:

```
var v = new { a = 100, b = 200, c = 300};
```

which its properties are dynamic?
I mean I'll create property names (a, b , c , ...) are not static and are in a variable itself:

```
var proppertyName1 = "a"; 
var proppertyName2 = "b"; 
var proppertyName3 = "c";
var v = new { proppertyName1 = 100, proppertyName2 = 200, proppertyName3 = 300}
```

Comment: what you want is ExpandoObject http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What you are going to do with `v` instance?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with an `ExpandoObject` and a cast to `IDictionary<string, object>` if you really have to:

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
var propertyA = "a";
(expando as IDictionary<string, object>)[propertyA] = "some value";

Console.WriteLine(expando.a);
```